# Activity not launching even after I add it in AndroidManifest file

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I'm new to Android. I read similar posts but I cannot solve my problem.
I added all my activities in androidManifest file, but I cannot move from Second Activity to ThirdActivity using Intent.

### Here is MainActivity.java

```
package com.mobi.crazycalc;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.Handler;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.view.Menu;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(in);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 1000);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
 }

 }
```

### here is SecondActivity.java

```
package com.mobi.crazycalc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
EditText name1;
EditText name2;
Button goButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    name1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1);
    name2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name2);
    goButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
    final String hisName=name1.getText().toString().trim();
    final String herName=name2.getText().toString().trim();
    goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Love lv=new Love();
            int result=lv.getLovePer(hisName, herName);
            Intent in=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("Result", result);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return true;
     }

    }
```

### Here is ThirdActivity.java

```
package com.mobi.crazycalc;

import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {
 TextView meter;
 Button goBackButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);
    meter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meter);
    goBackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gobackbutton);
    goBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in=new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    Random ran= new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
    {
        int ranNo=ran.nextInt(100);
        meter.setText(ran.toString());
    }
Bundle bund=getIntent().getExtras();
int res=bund.getInt("Result");

    meter.setText(res);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.third, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

### this is the manifest file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mobi.crazycalc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobi.crazycalc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobi.crazycalc.SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobi.crazycalc.ThirdActivity"
        >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity-second.xml:

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e52850"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/name1Edittext"
    android:textColor="@color/almond" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gobutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/buttontext"
    android:textColor="@color/aeroBlue" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/name1"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/name2Edittext"
    android:textColor="@color/almond" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you also give the code of `R.layout.activity_second`, please? Thanks!

Comment: Try it without `MainActivity.this.finish();` ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting and try this in your goButton where you have declare your Intent ,,,,, intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Comment: i have put the activity_second.xml

Comment: this.finish();     <---- after startActivity();

Comment: try using :

Intent in=new Intent(ThirdActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
SecondActivity.this.startActivity(in);

Comment: this.finish(); dosent work.....

Comment: it throws following error:  Fatal Exception: main JAva.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity component info{ com.mobi.crazycalc.thirdActivity}:android.content res.Resource not Found Exception

Comment: Anyone please help.. i want this problem to be solved as soon as possible ...  :(

Comment: do i have to add <intent-filter> for both SecondActivity and ThirdActivity? Both the activities use intents so should i include?

Comment: no, the intent filter of your main activity just says that main activity is the activity to start. for other activities intent filters are not necessary.

can you post the layout.xml for your third activity please. it seems you are using an id, which is not available in your layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This one

And you can check this [here](https://github.com/NewRajesh/crazycalc)

In MainActiviy

```
package com.mobi.crazycalc;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(in);
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

In SecondAcivity

```
package com.mobi.crazycalc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText name1;
    EditText name2;
    Button goButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1);
        name2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name2);
        goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
        final String hisName = name1.getText().toString().trim();
        final String herName = name2.getText().toString().trim();
        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("Result", "value");
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In Third activity

```
package com.mobi.crazycalc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class ThirdActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView meter;
    Button goBackButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        meter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meter);
        goBackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gobackbutton);
        goBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        Random ran = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            int ranNo = ran.nextInt(100);
            meter.setText(ran.toString());
        }
        Bundle bund = getIntent().getExtras();
        String res = bund.get("Result").toString();

        meter.setText(res);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_third, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and In menifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobi.crazycalc" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ThirdActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_third" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i have updated the answer check this https://github.com/NewRajesh/crazycalc. and let me know if you have any problem.